# MVC Project Can Not Be Found on Android Browser

Tags: android, ios, model-view-controller, iis

I have an MVC mobile website hosted on IIS, deployed and running just fine inside of a corporate network. The issue I am having is that this site "can't be found" on android mobile devices. iOS seems to be able to find and load the website with no problem. I have tried multiple browsers on Android and all of them fail to find the website and display a "website can not be found" error.

I know my devices are correctly connected to the wireless network and *should* be able to access the site. Is there a setting or configuration I am missing for Android that will allow the site to load? Or is there just a fundamental difference that will not allow me to access the site.

tl;dr: iOS can access a hosted site on company network by not Android, how can I fix this?

Edit: This seems to be related to a bug in android that prevents proper resolution of host names. So instead of navigating to

```
http://devserver:8080
```

I needed to use the ip address instead:

```
http://192.168.1.1:8080
```

Is there a workaround or fix for this issue?

Comment: This sounds more like a DNS problem. Check how the DNS is set up on both your Android and iOS devices and compare.

Comment: Hmm both are set up for DHCP nothing special about the DNS was configured on either of the devices.

Comment: Anything in the logcat? Can you see the specific error? Is this http or https?

Comment: Not familar with logcat, and no it doesn't give me an error code. Http

Comment: Added some additional information and yes it seems to be related to DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer use the fully qualified domain name

instead of:

```
http://devserver:8080
```

use:

```
http://devserver.corporatedomain.com:8080
```

Comment: That means that your DHCP server isn't delivering the default domain and/or search domains correctly, or it isn't delivering the DNS server addresses correctly. You should check that.

Comment: I actually thing this is android specific

Comment: Not likely. Android DNS resolution works just fine, if the DHCP server is properly configured.

Comment: http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/21/google-acknowledges-2-5-year-old-networking-bug-promises-fix-in-next-android-version/